# Bootstrap image stuck to top of screen

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a class I have to create a website that has a picture right below the navigation bar, but for some reason that I can't figure out, the picture is displaying within the navigation bar and not below it. Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks

```
<div class="row">
 <nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
        <li><a href="###">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Special Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Breakfast</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Lunch</a></li>
        <li><a href="###" class="active">Liam's Food Fusion</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Dinner</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Apps and Extras</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Online Ordering</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Contact Us</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
</nav>
  </div>
 <!--    end navigation  -->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-4" id="logopic">
    <img src="images/food fusion logo.png" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position:fixed` that the class `navbar-fixed-top` has causes the nav element to site above (think 3D) everything on the page. So whats happening to the image is that it's sitting at what it thinks is the top of the page with the the navbar over the top.

So pretty much you can just remove the `.navbar-fixed-top` class from the nav element or add a margin top to the div surrounding the content following the nav bar (in this case `<div class="row">`.

Heres a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lucasjm/pen/dqzqaX) with an example.

Answer (score 1):

`navbar-fixed-top`'s css is using absolute positioning to place it at the top of everything else. Using absolute positioning in css doesn't push other containers below it, it simply positions itself above them.

If you want to move the next div down, you can add padding or margin to it equal to the navbar's height if you know it, or by using relative positioning instead of absolute.

Looking at the Inspect of this bootstrap example might help you understand https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ . 
Notice the `body` tag in Fixed Top example has a top padding. The Static Top example the `body` does not have padding top because the navbar is placed using relative positioning instead of absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set your class in the `nav` element like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

and add the following CSS

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

(per docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

See demo below:

```css
.body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
      <li><a href="###">Locations</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">Special Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">Breakfast</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">Lunch</a></li>
      <li><a href="###" class="active">Liam's Food Fusion</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">Dinner</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">Apps and Extras</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">Online Ordering</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!--    end navigation  -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the class should be "navbar navbar-fixed-top" I believe

Comment: @KevinLewis hmm, let me check

Comment: @KevinLewis you are correct! - I was referencing v4.1 which uses a different approach. - Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the navbar is using the "navbar-fixed-top" class, it is fixed and therefore does not affect the placement of other elements.  What you should do is add a margin to the top of image or one of its containers.  Also, I'm fairly certain you don't need the  outside the navigation bar, it may be messing some stuff up.